# R inverted regex pattern for ls

Tags: regex, r

In R I load one environment from a file that contains various timeseries plus one configuration object/vector.

I want to process all timeseries in the environment in a loop but want to exclude the configuration object.

At the moment my code is like this:

```
for(x in ls(myEnv)) {
    if(x!="configData") {

        # do something, e. g.
        View(myEnv[[x]], x)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use the *pattern* parameter of the ls-function to omit the if clause?

```
for(x in ls(myEnv, pattern="magic regex picks all but *configData*")) {

    # do something, e. g.
    View(myEnv[[x]], x)
}
```

All examples I could find for pattern were based on a whitelist-approach (positive list), but I'd like to get all except *configData*.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What about something like `for( x in setdiff(ls(myEnv), "configData") )` instead?

Comment: `for(x in grep("configData", ls(), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)) ...` should work, too

Comment: If `ls()` used PCRE, a pattern of `^(?!configData)` would have worked but there doesn't seem to be a way to easily set `perl=TRUE` or `invert=TRUE` for that matter. If would be nice if that config variable had a leading "." to make it "hidden" so you wouldn't have this problem. Or put all the objects of interested into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for( x in setdiff(ls(myEnv), "configData") )
```

and

```
for(x in grep("configData", ls(myEnv), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE))
```

both work fine, thanks.

BTW, cool! I wasn't aware of **hiding** it by using a leading "." ... so the best solution for me is to make sure that configData becomes .configData in the source file so that ls() won't show it.

Comment: If you're applying the same function to everything in an environment, check out `eapply` (and the `all.names` argument for specifying whether to include things that begin with a dot or not)